# Android Studio : How does SVN ignore work?

Tags: svn, android-studio, gradle, svnignore, android-studio-import

I'm trying to understand how "SVN ignore" works in Android Studio.

Supposing that an user (userA) makes an android project with Android Studio,and then he shares the project to svn. Before committing, he decides to put in "ignore" some files and folders. 
In the particular case : 
 1. .idea/workspace.xml (file)
 2. .gradle (folder)
 3. build/ (folder)
 4. local.properties (file)
 5. app.iws (file)
 6. .idea/libraries/ (folder)

Now, userA commits, and all the project is in the svn, except the ignored list above. If userA check his "ignored files" (File->Settings->Version Control-> Ignored Files) he can see the list.

Now another user (userB) decides to import the project from svn. He takes the userA's project.
UserB now has the project from svn, his own workspace.xml file (different from UserA) but, if he check the Android Studio Version Control->Ignored Files, he has the same list of UserA.

How it is possible? Where this list is stored? (I see something only in workspace.xml,but the file is not in svn)

Thanks a lot.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore-list is metadata, stored inside repository (`svn help propset`) and transferred with it (read about SVN-properties and `svn:ignore` as part of it)